# Tortoise Hg not working on ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, mercurial

I have installed Tortoise Hg in my ubuntu 18.04. Its getting installed without any issues but when I am trying to open it, it doesn't open. I have tried installing it through both terminal and ubuntu software packages. Can anyone help me to sort out this problem?

Comment: I can't find any files regarding Tortoise Hg in .config directory after installation.

Answer (score 0):

Please execute below commands in terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install tortoisehg
```

As mentioned in [How to Install tortoisehg in Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.howtoinstall.me/ubuntu/18-04/tortoisehg/).

This worked for me.

Comment: Agilan Selvam already tried that.